# TypeScript says type has no call signatures despite asserting typeof === "function"

Tags: typescript, static-analysis

I have a type that looks like this:

```ts
type Config<T, U> = {
  A: T | (() => T);
  B: U | (() => U);
}
```

with the goal being to allow a user to provide either a value, or a function returning a value, as a parameter to a function.

The function signature then looks like this:

```ts
const doesStuff = <T, U>(val: T, { A = val, B = val }: Config<T, U>): T | U => {
  // ... do stuff
  if (typeof A === "function") {
    return A(); // This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type '(() => T | U) | (T & Function) | (U & Function)' are callable. Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.
  }
}
```

This function performs some work on `val` and then optionally allows the callsite to override the return value if it would trigger conditions A or B, with the values supplied in the config.

I feel as though I'm being gaslit by TS static analysis here; on what earth is "this is a function" not good enough to guarantee that it's a callable expression?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of how you would call `doesStuff()`.  You have a lot of single letter variable names which makes this all hard to figure out `A`, `B`, `T`, `U` in your type and then again in your function. My attempt: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgGigVQD4oBeKAbwCgooBBALiiygB8oAKdgSlOKy4Dc1KACFG+Vh268CgygF9KlAMaIAzsCgATOBDUBlYAFckSUlGx4i7AG4BDADaNcFOufsOo8xvGTpLBIQ8JMRUNAD04VAAdLHacFAaJkjCqghqcA4Q0Q5waOwA5KCQjAV4xRBwZrRcwihm7BVVbiStUABESEYIysAoiO08YTRQAE4QxqMIdNxCNIqKlDp6hsmFSHBwZRzBocI0aRlZOXmFABYQDrkFtfKCQA)

Comment: The issue is primarily that `T` might itself be a function type, and some functions require arguments.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3VgjN) for how it could go wrong.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (unless I find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: followup: found the dupe target, see the linked question/answers for more info